# How to delete the NSManagedObject instance from Data Source?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, tableview

I am trying to override `tableView:commitEditingStyle:editingStyleforRowAtIndexPath:` and having trouble implementing the deletion of the actual instance of a `NSManagedObject` that is represented in that row.

Apple says it should be done with the following code([Shown Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/06_Deleting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH108-SW1)):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    // Delete the managed object at the given index path.
    NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [eventsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:eventToDelete];

    // Update the array and table view.
    [eventsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];

    // Commit the change.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
    }
}
}
```

When I mimick this sample code in my app, every line works except for one line.  The one line is: `[bowlerArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`.  I get the error "Receiver type 'NSArray' for instance message does not declare a method with selector 'removeObjectAtIndex'".

What should that one line of code be?

Note: My line `NSManagedObject *eventToDelete = [bowlerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` works just fine.

Update: Posting my actual code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObject *objectToDelete = [bowlerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [moc deleteObject:objectToDelete];

    [bowlerArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}   
else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
}   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSArray` is immutable, so you can't modify it.
`removeObjectAtIndex` is not part of the `NSArray API`, because it would modify it.
You need an `NSMutableArray` to be able to do that.

---

If I do this :

```
NSMutableArray *arMu = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", nil];
[arMu removeObjectAtIndex:0];
self.bigLabel.text = [arMu objectAtIndex:0];
```

the bigLabel is showing 1 for the index 0.
You error message is suggesting that you still have a NSArray instead of an NSMutableArray for the variable `eventsArray`

---

You can make a NSMutableArray from a NSArray like this :

```
NSMutableArray *arMu = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:someNSArray];
```

Comment: after making that change, I get the following error when trying to delete.  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_PFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb65fb60'.

Comment: could you post that change, because `- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index` is a valid selector for a NSMutableArray.

Comment: in my viewWillAppear: method where my bowlerArray gets populated via a line `bowlerArray = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];` has a warning of "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *_strong' from NSArray *'.

Comment: That is your problem, don't disregard warning in Xcode, Objective-C is a very unsafe language, so warning should be treated as errors. Back to the problem, `a fetchRequest return a NSArray not a NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Do I need to force the fetchRequest to return a NSMutableArray? or convert the NSArray after the fetchRequest?

Comment: @tarheel I don't think you can force it to return a NSMutableArray, you have to make one.

Comment: Finally got it all working with editing my fetch request line to `bowlerArray = [[moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];` Thanks for the help!